# Bind select dropdown from json object in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs

I'm new to Angular and this is my first major hurdle. I have the following JSON object returned from a third-party API of address data that's been added to $scope.AddressData in a controller:

```
$scope.AddressData = [{
  "Address1":"South Row",
  "Address2":"Horsforth",
  "Address3":null,
  "Address4":null,
  "Town":"Leeds",
  "County":"West Yorkshire",
  "Postcode":"LS18 4AA",
  "PremiseData":"12;||13;||14;"
}];
```

As you can see, I have multiple premises for one street. What I want to achieve is to have a select box that has one line per PremiseData item with the other fields appended to it.

Given the example above, I want the HTML to be:

```
<select name="premises">
  <option value="12 South Row, Horsforth, Leeds, West Yorkshire"></option>
  <option value="13 South Row, Horsforth, Leeds, West Yorkshire"></option>
  <option value="14 South Row, Horsforth, Leeds, West Yorkshire"></option>
</select>
```

Also, once an item is selected, I want to populate other inputs with the relevant data.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: This is more of a JavaScript problem Brett. You just need to separate those PremiseData's by `;||` and create an object for each one based on that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more JavaScript related than Angular, but you just need to separate those `PremiseData`'s and build your own object.

**[jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hw6L2tnL/)**

```
// No point in adding this to your scope since you're not using it there
var addressData = [{
  "Address1":"South Row",
  "Address2":"Horsforth",
  "Address3":null,
  "Address4":null,
  "Town":"Leeds",
  "County":"West Yorkshire",
  "Postcode":"LS18 4AA",
  "PremiseData":"12;||13;||14;"
}];

$scope.addresses = [];

for (var i = 0; i < addressData.length; i++) {

    // Remove that last " ; "
    addressData[i].PremiseData = addressData[i].PremiseData.substr(0, addressData[i].PremiseData.length - 1);

    // Split by ;||
    var premises = addressData[i].PremiseData.split(';||');

    // Build new address
    for (var n = 0; n < premises.length; n++) {
        var address = premises[n] + ' ' 
            + addressData[i].Address1 + ' '
            + addressData[i].Address2 + ' '
            + addressData[i].Town + ' '
            + addressData[i].County;

        // Add this built address to your 
        $scope.addresses.push(address);        
    }
}
```

Then in your html you simply use `ng-options` to loop through those `addresses`, and voila!

```
<select ng-model="selectedAddress" ng-options="a as a for a in addresses"></select>
```